# Match the values of two dataframes and return a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
       {   
            "index":    ["December",  "December",  "November", "November"],
            "index1":   ["285",       "296",       "397",      "300"]})


     index     index1
0   December    285
1   December    296
2   November    397
3   November    300
```

And also o second dataframe like this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "index":     ["December",  "December",  "November", "November"],
        "index1":    ["285",       "296",       "397",      "300"],
        "eventid":   ["67511",     "67512",     "64515",    "64517"]})


     index     index1    eventid
0   December    285       67511
1   December    296       67512
2   November    397       64515
3   November    300       64517
```

I want to match `index` & `index1` of `df1` and `index` & `index1` of `df2` and return the `eventid` of `df2` in a dictionary

For example:

For the first row of `df1 % df2`:

`0 December 285` of `df1` matches with `0 December 285` of `df2` so the dictionary will be

```
{285: 67511}
```

For the second row of `df1 % df2`:

`1 December 296` of `df1` matches with `1 December 296` of `df2` so the dictionary will be

```
{285: 67511, 296:67512}
```

The first and second rows go together as they have the same index value (i.e December).

And so on for the other rows

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframes then [`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the resulting dataframe by `index` and create the record for each unique `index` inside a dict comprehension

```
{k: dict(zip(g['index1'], g['eventid'])) 
    for k, g in df2.merge(df1).groupby('index')}
```

---

```
{'December': {'285': '67511', '296': '67512'},
 'November': {'397': '64515', '300': '64517'}}
```

Comment: i am trying to understand your code. Can you please add some comments or provide a solution with no list comprehension?